# Azure Security Centre - Can't get rid of 90044-Allowed Null Session recommendation

Tags: azure, azure-security-center

I have 8 different Windows Server 2016 and 2019 Virtual Machines in one of my Azure subscriptions.

Of these, 7 of them report a fail on the ***90044-Allowed Null Session*** check in Azure Security Centre as shown here:

[image]

The CVE links go to information that is either unrelated or so ridiculously out of date it's older than Methuselah.

When following the links in the 'Remediation' section, [the first one goes 404](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/143474/restricting-information-available-to-anonymous-logon-users) and the [second one take me to an eons-old Server 2000 Documentation link that recommends setting a specific Registry entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc957461(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). This setting is already present and configured as recommended by default.

I've done some Googling around and found this [Windows 10 link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-restrict-anonymous-access-to-named-pipes-and-shares) which has instructions on configuring the setting in GP, again this is configured as recommended on all VMs. [Also found this from Blumira](https://www.blumira.com/integration/how-to-disable-null-session-in-windows/) which has a more detailed run down of additional Registry and Group Policy settings that should be applied. I can confirm that all servers are configured as per the recommendations here as well.

So my question is on what criteria is this recommendation appearing, and how so I configure my VMs to satisfy the requirements of this recommendation?

Any help would be very greatly appreciated, this is making a significant dent in my ASC score (6 points, or -10%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this, there is a registry entry that was not set as required on the affected machines:

**HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\RestrictAnonymous**

This is defaulted to '0' on all affected VMs, set this to **'1' (Null sessions can not be used to enumerate shares)** and the machines will then pass the requirements for the check.

Any/all other settings to pass this check appear to be as required by default on the standard Windows Server 2016/2019 images used in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group Policy to control this setting **Network access: Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and Shares** security policy setting.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-access-restrict-anonymous-access-to-named-pipes-and-shares

Comment: If you read the information I provided above carefully enough, you will see that I have already checked, and found that set as suggested by default.

Comment: @ChrisButler ,The above answer I have suggested seemed to have solved the issue here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/369929/unable-to-remove-vulnerability-9004-allowed-null-s.html . if that doesn't help  then , I would suggest to raise a Support request (help+support) from azure portal to get the technical assistance from azure team.